# php class InvalidArgumentException exception is how to determine the parameter type?

Tags: php

php exception class InvalidArgumentException how to use. I can not distinguish the difference between this class with other exception classes. He specifically used in what circumstances? Is how to determine the parameter type. Even if it seems you can not determine the parameter type normally throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Invalidargumentexception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) isthrown  thrown if an argument is not of the expected type.

From the documentation ..

```
InvalidArgumentException extends LogicException {
```

#The properties which are inhertited

```
protected string $message ;
protected int $code ;
protected string $file ;
protected int $line ;
```

## The methods which are inherited

```
final public string Exception::getMessage ( void )
final public Exception Exception::getPrevious ( void )
final public mixed Exception::getCode ( void )
final public string Exception::getFile ( void )
final public int Exception::getLine ( void )
final public array Exception::getTrace ( void )


final public string Exception::getTraceAsString ( void )

public string Exception::__toString ( void )



final private void Exception::__clone ( void )



}
```